# using map in collapsible table reactjs

Tags: reactjs, loops, dictionary, indexing, key

I have a collapsible table which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2XZB.png). However when I click one row, both rows will expand.

This is what my code looks like:

```
const Transaction = ({ categories }) => {
 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

let categoryList = categories.map((category, index) => {
    return (
        <TableRow key={index}>
          <TableCell>
            <IconButton size="small" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
              {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {category}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell />
          <TableCell />
          <TableCell />
          <TableCell />
        </TableRow>
      );
  });

 return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell />
                  <TableCell>Category</TableCell>
                  <TableCell />
                  <TableCell />
                  <TableCell />
                  <TableCell />
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {categoryList}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In my categoryList, I used index as the key but it still expands both rows instead of the specific row selected. How can I make only one row to expand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table rows need to control their own `open` state. Currently, the way you structured your code they are both sharing the same state and clicking either of the table rows will refer to the same handler which changes the `open` state, so that's why both your table rows are both opening and closing together.

So instead of having `open` hold a single boolean, this solution has it hold an array of booleans all set to false initially.

```
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(categories.map(() => false));
```

This will create an array of booleans the size of `categories`.

Also, naturally the `OnClick` function will have to change a bit:

```
onClick={() => {
  setOpen((pOpen) => pOpen.map((o, i) => {
    if (i === index) return !o;
    return o;
  }));
}}
```

Now you can use the index `open[index]` to know what is open.

```
{open[index] ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
```

The full snippet is below:

```
const Transaction = ({ categories }) => {
 /* 
  * Change this [Origninal]:
  * const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  * To this:
  */
 const [open, setOpen] = useState(categories.map(() => false));


  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (categories.length !== open.length) {
      setOpen(categories.map(() => false));
    }
  }, [categories, open]);


let categoryList = categories.map((category, index) => {
    return (
        <TableRow key={index}>
          <TableCell>
            <IconButton size="small" 
                        onClick={() => {
                          setOpen((pOpen) => pOpen.map((o, i) => {
                            if (i === index) return !o;
                            return o;
                          }));
                        }}
              {open[index] ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {category}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell />
          <TableCell />
          <TableCell />
          <TableCell />
        </TableRow>
      );
  });

 return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell />
                  <TableCell>Category</TableCell>
                  <TableCell />
                  <TableCell />
                  <TableCell />
                  <TableCell />
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {categoryList}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I am getting a Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. How can I add key to pOpen.map?